# How to fetch data from controller to views in CakePHP or Yii

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp, yii, html-parsing, codeigniter-2

How to fetch data from controller to views in CakePHP or Yii but not embed PHP code in views file (view is html file).

it similar Template Parser Class in Codeigniter: 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load the data in the action controller by calling one of the model functions like findAll()
here is an example, assume we have a User model, and you need to pull out all the data and render them at view file:

```
public function actionIndex(){
$model = Users::model()->findAll();
$this->render('index', array('model' => model));
//the model variable will be defined in the index.php
//file and will have a value as assigned in the array

//index.php file should be located under /views/users/index.php
}
```

Now in index.php file do a `var_dump` and see what results you got.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with embedding php into HTML. But if you really don't want to do it, you can use CakePHP with a template library like Mustache.

Check this: https://github.com/electblake/CakePHP-Mustache-Plugin